# JavaFX Tableview header color when sorting is enabled

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to change the color of my header, but everytime I sort the rows by clicking on one of the column headers it becomes this:

[image]

How do i paint the "sorting arrow" background blue so that the whole header becomes blue and the arrow white? Thanks for any help.

**Edit 1**

By using @xtractic code i managed to get what i wanted:

[image]

Comment: Is your question is specifically on how to make each column background to blue only when "sort arrow is displayed" or you want to show all columns in blue by default?

Comment: hmm ... looks terrible from a UX perspective: now there's no immediate visual clue as to where one column ends (and can be resized, f.i.)

Comment: @kleopatra so what would you recommend? I am learning how to use JavaFx so I don't know a lot about its features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some useful css to help you:

```
/** color everything under the column header */
.table-view .column-header * {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}

/** color the arrow */
.table-view .column-header .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

/** color the column header text */
.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

/** add slight dividers between headers */
.table-view .column-header {
    -fx-border-color: white;
    -fx-border-width: .1
}

/** color the scroll bar background and thumb */
.table-view .scroll-bar {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.table-view .scroll-bar .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Is the .1 in the border width a pixel?

Comment: Smaller than a pixel, it causes it to blend a little which is an effect I like. Also note that I found there's still some slight uncolored background just slightly around the arrow for me, I'm working on taking care of that too.

Comment: @JeanWillianS.J. adding  `.table-view .column-header *` will color everything under the table header, from there you can set the arrows color specifically.